# What are restrictions for junior tennis players on number of senior tournaments?

Tags: tennis, tournaments, atp, wta, itf

Recently in a discussion I have heard that young players can only enter a limited number of senior tournaments. The number depends on the age of the player. (This information was mentioned in an interview with a coach of a girls' singles grand-slam champion, when discussing her transition into competing at senior level.) I would like to know more about these limits.

> What are limits for the number of senior tournaments a junior player can enter. Do they depend on age? Are they different for men/women?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ATP World Tour / Challenger**

According to [section 7](http://www.atpworldtour.com/~/media/20E5AA6B543C4E0CB7BD177759423CC5.ashx) of the [ATP Rulebook](http://www.atpworldtour.com/Corporate/Rulebook.aspx), the following restrictions apply for male players:

> **7.02 Entries**
>
> *A. Gender / Age Limitation*
>
> The ATP will use the age of a player on the first (1st) day of the
>   qualifying competition. Male players age sixteen (16) or older are not
>   limited in the number of tournaments they may enter. Players under the
>   age of sixteen (16) are subject to the following entry restrictions in
>   ATP World Tour or ATP Challenger Tour tournaments (includes entry as a
>   wildcard):
>
> 1. Male players under the age of fourteen (14) shall not be eligible for entry into any ATP World Tour or ATP Challenger Tour tournament.
> 2. Male players aged fourteen (14) shall be eligible for entry into a maximum of eight (8) ATP World Tour or ATP Challenger Tour
>      tournaments.
> 3. Male players aged fifteen (15) shall be eligible for entry into a maximum of twelve (12) ATP World Tour and ATP Challenger Tour
>      tournaments.

Answer (score 1):

**WTA/ITF - Women Competitions**

For more details you can look into
[2015 WTA Official Rulebook](http://www.wtatennis.com/SEWTATour-Archive/Archive/AboutTheTour/rules2015.pdf) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.wtatennis.com/SEWTATour-Archive/Archive/AboutTheTour/rules2015.pdf)). Briefly summarized it says in the section **XV. Age eligibility and player development** that:

> - Players under 14 cannot enter tournaments on WTA or ITF Women's Circuit.
> - Above 14 players can play in Fed Cup.
> - 14 years old player can play at 8 ITF Women's Circuit tournaments. (This limit is on the number of tournaments between her 14th and 15th birthday.)
> - 15 years old player can play 10 tournaments (and WTA Finals or WTA Elite Trophy if she qualifies).
> - 16 years old player can play 12 tournaments  (and WTA Finals or WTA Elite Trophy if she qualifies).
> - 17 years old player can play 16 tournaments  (and WTA Finals or WTA Elite Trophy if she qualifies).
> - For players that reached 18 years there is no limit on the number of professional tournaments.

**ITF - Junior Competitions**

There are also limits on the number of junior tournaments a player may enter. Again, for more details see [2014 Junior Circuit Regulations](http://www.itftennis.com/media/163398/163398.pdf) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.itftennis.com/media/163398/163398.pdf)).

I will reproduce here the table from that document (Appendix G: ITF junior circuit age eligibility rule) which gives an overview.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   Age | Number of Tournaments permitted                           |
|   18  | Unrestricted                                              |
|   17  | Unrestricted                                              |
|   16  | 25                                                        |
|   15  | 16 (and 4 additional tournaments for players in Top 20)   |
|   14  | 14 (and 4 additional tournaments for players in Top 20)   |
|   13  | 10 (and 4 additional tournaments for players in Top 50)   |
| 11/12 | 0                                                         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: I did not find anything about Boys' and Men tournaments. If I find some information about this, I will update my answer.